# How to sign already built Debian package?

Tags: debian, repository, packaging, signature

I have a project with a custom build-system, so the Debian package is just one of a targets: I do it with `dpkg-deb`.

But now I want to upload my package to some enterprise repo - and I need some files like `.dsc` and `.changes`, also they should be signed with PGP.

What is the easiest way to sign already built package and generate those files?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for an *easy way to build a repository* for your package(s), with signing.

There're [lots of hard ways](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository), and some tools to take the pain out of this task, where the easiest might be [aptly](http://www.aptly.info).  It features many common repository-related tasks, such as mirroring other repos, importing packages from mirrors, etc.  It furthermore defaults to signing repositories properly.  [They're offering deb packages, too.](http://www.aptly.info/#download)

A less feature-full but therefore maybe better solution for your task at hand is [Freight](https://github.com/rcrowley/freight), [see this blog post for an introduction](http://rcrowley.org/articles/packaging.html). [You can also get it in form of a package, including man pages and some helpers.](https://github.com/rcrowley/freight#from-a-debian-archive)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for debsign(1). You'll likely have to install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install devscripts
```

#### Usage

```
$ debsign -h
Usage: debsign [options] [changes, dsc or commands file]
  Options:
    -r [username@]remotehost
                    The machine on which the changes/dsc files live.
                    A changes file with full pathname (or relative
                    to the remote home directory) must be given in
                    such a case
    -k<keyid>       The key to use for signing
    -p<sign-command>  The command to use for signing
    -e<maintainer>  Sign using key of <maintainer> (takes precedence over -m)
    -m<maintainer>  The same as -e
    -S              Use changes file made for source-only upload
    -a<arch>        Use changes file made for Debian target architecture <arch>
    -t<target>      Use changes file made for GNU target architecture <target>
    --multi         Use most recent multiarch .changes file found
    --re-sign       Re-sign if the file is already signed.
    --no-re-sign    Don't re-sign if the file is already signed.
    --debs-dir <directory>
                    The location of the .changes / .dsc files when called from
                    within a source tree (default ..)
    --no-conf, --noconf
                    Don't read devscripts config files;
                    must be the first option given
    --help          Show this message
    --version       Show version and copyright information
  If a commands or dsc or changes file is specified, it and any .dsc files in
  the changes file are signed, otherwise debian/changelog is parsed to find
  the changes file.

Default settings modified by devscripts configuration files:
  (none)
```